# Run a bash for-loop on a stream

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm using Git Bash for Windows.  I want to `find` every folder named `foo` and open it in explorer with the command `start`.

```sh
for x in $(find . -name '*foo*' -type d 2> /dev/null); do
  start "$x"
done
```

I would like the folders to open as they are discovered, as opposed to all at once after the `find` command is complete.  Note that `start` will open the folder and exit immediately.

How can I treat my `find` command as a stream and tell bash to run the loop after any new line is printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `-exec` primary.

```
find . -name '*foo*' -type d -exec start {} \;
```

Comment: This is also better because it works correctly if the filename contains spaces.

Comment: This didn't *quite* work for me because git bash plays fast and loose with paths sometimes.  Windows's `start` command expects a Windows path, and bash provides a posix one, even if I try replacing the `/` with ``\`` with variable substitution.  It's "smart" that way.  I ended up using `-exec sh -c 'powershell -Command start "$(realpath "{}" | sed -e "s/^\\/\([a-z]\)/\\1:/i")" | sed -e "s/\\//\\\\/g"' \;`.